# Group Theory: Show that the following group is finite??

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am struggling with this one, I have no idea what the hint has to do with the problem or how to use it.

What we know: $a$, $b$ are from the General Linear Group over $\mathbb{C}$, so $a,b \in GL(2, \mathbb{C})$. And $a$ has order 3, $b$ has order 4. And 
$bab^{-1} = a^2$.

> G is a subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ generated by $a$ and $b$. Show that G is a finite group and find it's order(Hint: Use $ba =a^2b$).

I think I can use Lagrange's theorem to find the order bit but I cannot show that it is finite.
I mean, I tried expanding for some $(ba)^n$ but that doesn't help, I can't find it's order and the same goes for $ab$ or basically most other combinations of $a$ and $b$.

Actually, I've never encountered a group with $two$ generators. How do I do this...???

Help really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's $ba = a^2 b$, right?

Comment: No, it"s $ba=a^2b^{-1}=a^2b^3$...

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting it. The assumption is $bab^{-1} = a^2$ and that's equivalent to $ba = a^2 b$. Or are there more computations involved (which I don't see) such that one gets $ba = a^2 b^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes sorry, that was a typo...nonetheless, it still doesn't make sense to me at all!

Comment: What doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $G$ is generated by $a$ and $b$ means that the elements of $G$ are exactly the elements of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ which can be made by multiplying $a$ and $b$.

If $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ were abelian, a general element would be easy to write down succinctly: it would just be $a^nb^m$. But $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ is not abelian; this is where the hint comes in.

An element of $G$ is of the form
$$a^{n_1}b^{n_2}\cdots a^{n_{k-1}}b^{n_k}$$ for some $n_i\in\mathbb Z$, $k\in\mathbb N$. Can you use the hint to simplify this expression to something of the form $a^nb^m$? What does this tell you about the order of $G$?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but that's the thing; I don't see anything I can use in the expansion $a^{n_1}b^{n_2}\cdots a^{n_{k-1}}b^{n_k}$... I don't see any $a^3$ nor $b^4$ or something useful..

Comment: @Melba1993 but that's where the hint comes in! It gives you a way of swapping $a$'s and $b$'s

Comment: Okay....I'll give it a thought, and see how it goes first. But actually, I am sorry to ask this, but why is it that you can say "$G$ generated by $a$ and $b$ means the elements of $G$ are exactly the elements of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$? If I recall correctly....they are a group of matrices under ordinary matrix multplication and has determinant of 1, yes...? Why could you assert $G$ is so..?

Comment: $G$ being generated by $a,b$ means that $G$ is the subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ formed of elements which can be made by multiplying $a$ and $b$

Comment: I give up, I can't see any way to simplify the equation...I mean, if the form is $a(ba)^{n_1}(ba)^{n_2)...}$ then it might seem feasible since $ba=a^2b^3$. But In the form you have above, $b^{n_2}a^{n_3}...$ so I cannot express it as $(ba)^m$ for whatever $m \in \mathbb{N}$. I don't see how else there's a possibility to apply the hint....I mean I understand that I need to "interchange" the $a$ and $b$s so namely show it is commutative, but no, I can't...

Answer (score 0):

$G$ is the set of all words in $a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1}$.

Since $a^{-1}=a^2=aa$ and $b^{-1}=b^3=bbb$, $G$ is the set of all words in $a$ and $b$.

Since $ba =a^2b$, we can move all $a$'s to the left and so $G$ is the set of all words of the form $a^m b^n$. Therefore, because we it is enough to take $m<3$ and $n<4$, there is only a finite number of possible words and the group is finite (of order at most $12$).

To find the order, consider when two words the form $a^m b^n$ can be equal.

Answer (score 0):

While the general element of $G$ s of the form $a^{n_1}b^{n_2}a^{n_3}b^{n_4}\cdots a^{n_{k-1}}b^{n_k}$, we can consider the subset $$S:=\{\,a^nb^m\mid n\in\Bbb N_0, m\in \Bbb N_0\,\}\subseteq G $$
and use $ba=a^2b$ to show that $S=G$:

**Lemma 1.** Let $A=\{\,k\in\Bbb N_0\mid b^ka\in S\,\}$. Then $A=\Bbb N_0$.

*Proof.*
Trivially, $0\in A$.
Assume $k\in A$, say $b^k=a^nb^m$. 
Then $$b^{k+1}a=b^kba=b^kab^2 =a^nb^mb^2=a^nb^{m+2}\in S$$
and hence also $k+1\in A$. The claim follows by induction. $_\square$

**Corollay.** $Sa\subseteq S$ and in fact $Sa^k\subseteq S$ for all $k\in\Bbb N_0$.

*Proof.* 
The first follows because in $a^nb^m\cdot a$ we have $b^ma\in S$ and clearly $a^nS\subseteq S$. Then the second part follows by induction. $_\square$

As also $Sb^k\subseteq S$ for all $k\in\Bbb N_0$, we conclude
$$ SS\subseteq S.$$
So if we now use that $S$ is actually finite (but nonempty) we conclude that $S$ is a subgroup (subgroup criterion for finite subgroups).
As it contains $a$ and $b$, we obtain
$$G=\langle a,b\rangle\le S\le G $$
and ultimately $G=S$.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed, answer; one question....for the proof of the lemma, why is is $b^kba=b^kab^2$? Isn't it $b^kba=b^ka^2b$ since $ba=a^2b$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the groups $C_3=\langle a\rangle,C_4=\langle b\rangle$. There is an automorphism of $C_3$ that has order $2$; namely inversion $\eta:C_3\to C_3$ which sends $a\mapsto a^{-1}$, and there is a group morphism $\Phi:C_4\to {\rm Aut}(C_3)$ that sends $b\mapsto \eta$. We can thus form the semidirect product $G=C_3\rtimes C_4$, this has order $12$ (since its underlying set is just $C_3\times C_4$) and is generated by $a,b$, which have order $3$ and $4$ respectively. Moreover $bab^{-1}=\eta(a)=a^{-1}=a^2$, since $a$ has order $3$. This characterizes $G$ completely: $G$ is presented as the group $$G=\langle a,b\mid a^3,b^4,bab^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle$$

You can now try to show that the subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb C)$ you've been given is isomorphic to $G$.